# How to login to a different database and continue working with default one?

Tags: laravel, authentication, multi-tenant

Imagine you have this inside .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=global
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=global
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

And you have one more connection inside `config/database.php` called tenant.

Now when I try to log in I switch the connection to tenant and I use the username and password from that database, I can log in, log out and all works fine.

But now I want to be able to log in with a user that doesn't exist in this tenant DB.

I started to overwrite the login() function like this:

Tip: remember that at this point the connection is set to tenant!

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $parts = explode(':', $request['username']);

    if ($parts[0] === 'global') {
        \DB::purge(\DB::getDatabaseName());
        \DB::reconnect('global');

        \Schema::connection('global')->getConnection()->reconnect();
    }
   ::::::::::::::::::
```

But this doesn't work... It doesn't switch the connection

I want to log in with a user from global DB and continue to work with tenant DB...

Is this even possible?

---

#### Update:

I already solved the part of how to switch the DB connection...
The problem is only authentication to a different one!

Comment: is it declared connection variable in your user model?

Comment: No. the connection not, but the table is

Comment: try to declare it, in every model with its connection to avoid problems

Comment: I don't have to because The connection switching for tenants is working without any problems... I just wan't to get authenticated on a different DB and continue working with current one.... It's like you open tenant.domain.com and then you want to use global.domain.com credentials.... I would imagine that I can just authenticate on different DB and then just continue to work with tenant DB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid having to play with the default database connection, you should create **two different** model per ***database authenticatable user*** with each one its own `$connection` declared on the model

```
class UserGlobal extends User
{
    protected $connection = 'global';
}

class UserTennant extends User
{
    protected $connection = 'tennant';
}
```

You will need to do multi-authentification middlewares or use laravel's auth using this guide [laravel simple multi-auth](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel) to have an idea.

```
// config/auth.php

    <?php

    [...]
    'guards' => [
        [...]
        'global' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'globals',
        ],
        'tennant' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'tennants',
        ],
    ],

    [...]
    'providers' => [
        [...]
        'globals' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\UserGlobal::class,
        ],
        'tennants' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\UserTennant::class,
        ],
    ],
```

You need also to declare both database connection in `config/database.php`

```
'connections' => [
    'global' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_GLOBAL', '127.0.0.1'),
            ...
            ],
    'tennant' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_TENNANT', '127.0.0.1'),
            ...
            ],
    ]
```

**What login would look like**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $tennant= $this->loginGuard($request->get('email'), $request->get('password'), auth('tennant'));
    $global= $this->loginGuard($request->get('email'), $request->get('password'), auth('global'));
    if (!$tennant && !$global) {
        return 'wrong credential';
    }
    return 'welcome';
}

private function loginGuard($email, $password, $guard)
{
    $token = $guard->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]);
    if (!$token || !$guard->user()->isLoggingIn()) {
        return null;
    }
    return $guard->user();
}
```

Comment: Yes and if I would do that I would be locked on one Database.... I hope you understand this... If I set the connection name inside model then I am on tenant connection and I would be logged in on that tenant.... But I don't want to log in with tenant credentials but instead with credentials from global db and then continue working with tenant connection....

Comment: @lewis4u I think in that case you just need to change the value of `config(['database.default' => 'global'])`

Comment: this is tricky, you would need to change the default connection at various middleware and login/reset_password/.... points. gonna edit my answer

Comment: Can you explain what do I get with another 'extended' User Model? And that tutorial has nothing to do with multiple databases....it's made for multi auth on a single database!

Comment: @lewis4u not really, it's multi auth on different models. Doesnt matter witch database each model uses. made a mistake in the first `$connection`. edited my answer.

Comment: OK, and how do you differentiate which user is logging in at a given time?
Is it a tenant user or is it a global user??? On the log in page I mean.

Comment: From the `guard` you are using, or you can get the class of the instance `get_class($user)`

Comment: The problem is that I have one log in page and you can log in as tenant without problem but I want to log in through the same login page with username that doesn't exist in this current tenants DB and that is the thing that makes it complicated. Laravel is made so that it uses the current DB connection when you click on submit on login page... and then I want to switch the connection but it doesn't work

Comment: @lewis4u I added an example of what a `login()` method whould look like