# multiple database in laravel Auth not working

Tags: php, laravel

we have 2 databases 1 for super admin and another for all users. we need super admin enabled to log in to all user panels.
Super admin login detail in super_admin_database

We try

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql2.database", 'connectable-v2-superadmin');
        if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            return ResponseController::sendError(__("You have successfully logged in!"), [$user],'$user');
            // $this->user = Auth::user();
            // $this->user->token = $this->user->createToken('ControlEscolar')->accessToken;
            // $status = 200;
        }
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496720/how-to-login-to-a-different-database-and-continue-working-with-default-one